# Does Karma rely on your source code being available in the browser's global scope?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-runner

This seems to be the only way that I can get my Jasmine tests to run through Karma at the moment:

src/js/voice.js

```
describe("speak", function () {
    var input = "Success";
    var output = Voice.prototype.speak(input);

    it("Should return the input value", function () {
        expect(output).toEqual(input);
    });
});
```

spec/voiceSpec.js

```
var Voice = function () {};

Voice.prototype.speak = function (string) {
    return string;  
};
```

Comment: Yes.  Karma needs the source code, the tests, and all of their dependencies to be injected into the browser's global scope.  You can't just include the test files in karma's configuration for it to work.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.